# R: adding up scores in a variable using mutate and case_when

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to create a score based on dummy variables, where different combinations add up to a certain 'stringency'.

```
set.seed(2)
df <- data.frame(id = 1:20,
                 a = rbinom(20, 1, 0.6),
                 b = rbinom(20, 1, 0.6),
                 c = rbinom(20, 1, 0.6),
                 d = rbinom(20, 1, 0.6),
                 e = rbinom(20, 1, 0.6))
```

Which looks like

```
id a b c d e
1 1 0 0 0 1
2 0 1 1 0 0
3 1 0 1 0 1
4 1 1 1 1 1
5 0 1 0 0 1
6 0 1 0 1 0
7 1 1 0 1 0
8 0 1 1 1 1
9 1 0 1 1 0
10 1 1 0 1 1
11 1 1 1 1 0
12 1 1 1 1 1
13 0 0 0 1 1
14 1 0 0 1 1
15 1 1 1 1 1
16 0 0 0 0 1
17 0 0 0 1 1
18 1 1 0 0 1
19 1 0 0 1 1
20 1 1 0 1 1
```

Now I am trying to create the following variable:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(stringency = case_when(a == 1 ~ 3,
                                           a == 1 & b == 1 ~ 6,
                                           a == 1 & c == 1 ~ 6,
                                           a == 1 & b == 1 & c ~ 7,
                                           a == 1 & d == 1 ~ 11,
                                           a == 1 & e == 1 ~ 9,
                                           a == 1 & b == 1 & d == 1 ~ 9,
                                           a == 1 & b == 1 & e == 1 ~ 9,
                                           TRUE ~ 0))
```

However, this produces a result where only the first argument works (`a == 1 ~ 3`)

```
id a b c d e stringency
1 1 0 0 0 1          3
2 0 1 1 0 0          0
3 1 0 1 0 1          3
4 1 1 1 1 1          3
5 0 1 0 0 1          0
6 0 1 0 1 0          0
7 1 1 0 1 0          3
8 0 1 1 1 1          0
9 1 0 1 1 0          3
10 1 1 0 1 1         3
11 1 1 1 1 0         3
12 1 1 1 1 1         3
13 0 0 0 1 1         0
14 1 0 0 1 1         3
15 1 1 1 1 1         3
16 0 0 0 0 1         0
17 0 0 0 1 1         0
18 1 1 0 0 1         3
19 1 0 0 1 1         3
20 1 1 0 1 1         3
```

What I want is that it 'builds up': if you have just a, you get 3; if you have a and b, you get 6; etc.

Any ideas on how I can do this? Many thanks

Comment: `case_when` stops on the first match. Reverse the order of your expressions from most selective to least selective.

Comment: You also need to be careful about the order of equally restrictive conditions.  For example `a==1 & c==1` is equally restrictive as `a==1 & e==1`, but depending on which comes first row 3 will either be 6 or 9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pay attention to the order of your conditions. `case_when` will stop if the first time a condition is `TRUE` and will not evaluate the rest. Therefore you want your most complex conditions at the beginning and `a == 1` at the end.

```r
library(dplyr)

set.seed(2)
df <- data.frame(id = 1:20,
                 a = rbinom(20, 1, 0.6),
                 b = rbinom(20, 1, 0.6),
                 c = rbinom(20, 1, 0.6),
                 d = rbinom(20, 1, 0.6),
                 e = rbinom(20, 1, 0.6))


df <- df %>% mutate(stringency = case_when(a == 1 & b == 1 & c == 1 ~ 7,
                                           a == 1 & b == 1 & d == 1 ~ 9,
                                           a == 1 & b == 1 & e == 1 ~ 9,
                                           a == 1 & d == 1 ~ 11,
                                           a == 1 & e == 1 ~ 9,
                                           a == 1 & b == 1 ~ 6,
                                           a == 1 & c == 1 ~ 6,
                                           a == 1 ~ 3,
                                           TRUE ~ 0))

df
#>    id a b c d e stringency
#> 1   1 1 0 0 0 1          9
#> 2   2 0 1 1 0 0          0
#> 3   3 1 0 1 0 1          9
#> 4   4 1 1 1 1 1          7
#> 5   5 0 1 0 0 1          0
#> 6   6 0 1 0 1 0          0
#> 7   7 1 1 0 1 0          9
#> 8   8 0 1 1 1 1          0
#> 9   9 1 0 1 1 0         11
#> 10 10 1 1 0 1 1          9
#> 11 11 1 1 1 1 0          7
#> 12 12 1 1 1 1 1          7
#> 13 13 0 0 0 1 1          0
#> 14 14 1 0 0 1 1         11
#> 15 15 1 1 1 1 1          7
#> 16 16 0 0 0 0 1          0
#> 17 17 0 0 0 1 1          0
#> 18 18 1 1 0 0 1          9
#> 19 19 1 0 0 1 1         11
#> 20 20 1 1 0 1 1          9
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

But as you can see in row 4, the result is 7, but if you change the order of the conditions it could be all other values as well, so you need to add some more conditions for clarity.